# VueJS2: How to check if array contains specific elements?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vue application with a series of checkboxes that add items to an array when the user selects a checkbox. There are about 6 items that could be selected, however, I need to reveal a `<div>` if 2 specific items are selected:

> Example array if all elements are checked:

```
["Apples", "Bananas", "Cucumbers", "Pears", "Peaches", "Strawberries"]
```

**But, if ONLY `Apples` and `Pears` are checked AND/OR if `Apples` OR `Pears` are checked, I need to reveal a `div` in the view with a set of instructions for the user.**

> I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<div v-if="(selectedProducts.length <= 2) && ( selectedProducts.includes('Apples') || selectedProducts.includes('Pears') )">
...show mycontent...
</div>
```

> In my vue instance I have initiated the data like so:

```
data: {
    selectedProducts: []
}
```

What's the correct way to write this logic? Should I use the array.every() method in this case? Thank you.

Comment: i think you need to replace your or conditional operator with and. || to &&. Because you'd need selected products to include both apples and pears selectedProducts.includes('Apples') && selectedProducts.includes('Pears') also use === 2 instead of length < 3 if you want specifically only the 2 products in question

Comment: my apologies, i just updated the question: I need to check whether BOTh are selected AND/OR if one of the other is checked. Sorry!

Comment: ( selectedProducts.includes('Apples') && selectedProducts.includes('Pears')) || ( selectedProducts.includes('Apples') || selectedProducts.includes('Pears') )? But the first statement is redundant because you're displaying the content whether in the case of both being shown or just one of them being shown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the DIV if both apples and pears are selected and only two items are selected, or if one item is selected and the product is either apples or pears.

If that's true, here is a computed that does that.

```
computed:{
  matched(){
    let pears = this.selectedProducts.includes("Pears")
    let apples = this.selectedProducts.includes("Apples")
    if (this.selectedProducts.length === 2 && pears && apples) return true
    if (this.selectedProducts.length === 1 && (apples || pears)) return true
    return false
  }
}
```

Working Example:

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    products: ["Apples", "Bananas", "Cucumbers", "Pears", "Peaches", "Strawberries"],
    selectedProducts: []
  },
  methods:{
    onChange(evt, product){
      if (evt.target.checked){
        this.selectedProducts.push(product)
      } else {
        this.selectedProducts.splice(this.selectedProducts.indexOf(product), 1)
      }
    }
  },
  computed:{
    matched(){
      let pears = this.selectedProducts.includes("Pears")
      let apples = this.selectedProducts.includes("Apples")
      if (this.selectedProducts.length === 2 && pears && apples) return true
      if (this.selectedProducts.length === 1 && (apples || pears)) return true
      return false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="product in products">
    <label for=""><input type="checkbox" :value="product" @change="onChange($event, product)"> {{product}}</label>
  </div>
  {{selectedProducts}}
  
  <hr>
  <div v-if="matched">
    Matched Criteria
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You could try

```
selectedProducts.indexOf('Apples') !== -1
```

Instead of

```
selectedProducts.includes('Apples')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare like this

```
 <div v-if="selectedProducts == 'Apples,Pears'  || selectedProducts == 'Apples' ||  selectedProducts == 'Pears' ">
     ...show mycontent...
 </div>
```

Comment: sorry, I had to update my question:  I need to check whether BOTh are selected AND/OR if one of the other is checked. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this should help you to find if a list have a certain element.

```
    if (cls.attributes.tags.includes("dance")) {
        console.log(cls.attributes.title);
      }
```